# Building multiple CON statements with OR/AND in ArcGIS Raster Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, con

I have two raster "T" and "N" which have values ranging from 0 to 1000. This is the logic that I want to query and create the new raster:

[image: query logic]

This is how I tried to query in a syntax-correct way in the Raster Calculator in ArcGIS, but the resulting raster only shows the value "1", but no error.

```
Con(("T.tif" < 50) & ("N.tif" < 40), 100, 0) | 
Con(("T.tif" < 50) | ("N.tif" < 40), 80, 0) |    
Con(("T.tif" < 55) & ("N.tif" < 45), 60, 0) | 
Con(("T.tif" < 55) | ("N.tif" < 45), 40, 0) | 
Con(("T.tif" < 60) & ("N.tif" < 50), 20, 0)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to use nested Con statements, like is described [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/conditional-evaluation-with-con.htm) to build your if-elif-else structure, instead of Con() | Con() | Con(). Instead of saying:

```
Con(queryA, trueA, falseA) | Con(queryB, trueB, falseB) | etc...
```

You should phrase it as:

```
Con(queryA, trueA, Con(queryB, trueB, Con(...)))
```

where the innermost Con() statement will have 0 as it's false value.